# Why can Flow reference a Class without it being imported?

Tags: flowtype

I don't understand why this is happening:

```
source/server.js:2
2: import type { Server } from "http"
               ^^^^^^ Named import from module `http`. This module has no named export called `Server`.
```

This is the module declaration:

```
declare module "http" {
  declare class Server extends net$Server {
  ...
```

## Update

Ok its clear now that `Server` is a value not a type and hence cannot be imported like a type and that in Flow JavaScript classes *can* be used at the type level. But I still do not understand one thing, why is `Server` able to be referenced as a type without being imported?

```
❯ yarn run flow
yarn run v0.24.6
$ "/Users/jason.kuhrt/projects/ssense/ms-fastly-purge/node_modules/.bin/flow"
No errors!
✨  Done in 0.18s.
```

`cat ./source/test-flow.js`

```
// @flow
const a: Server = 1
console.log(a)
```

`cat ./.flowconfig`

```
[ignore]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/build
<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow-typed

[include]

[libs]

[options]
```

`cat ./package.json`

```
{
  "name": "ms-fastly-purge",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags && release",
    "install-typings": "flow-typed install",
    "dev": "nodemon source/Main.js --exec babel-node",
    "lint": "eslint ./source",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:dev": "jest --watch",
    "build": "babel source/ --out-dir build/",
    "start": "node ./build/Main.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.1",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^11.2.0",
    "eslint-config-ssense": "^0.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.34.0",
    "eslint-plugin-fp": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^2.0.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.47.0",
    "flow-typed": "^2.1.2",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "moxios": "^0.4.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "prettier": "^1.3.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^6.2.3",
    "release": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ssense/node-logger": "^1.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "base62": "^1.2.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "convict": "^3.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "joi": "^10.5.2",
    "most": "^1.4.0",
    "newrelic": "^1.39.1",
    "ramda": "^0.24.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [],
    "presets": [
      [
        "env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ],
      "flow",
      "stage-3"
    ]
  }
}
```

If I change to something that should fail like `Server1` it indeed fails:

```
❯ yarn flow
yarn flow v0.24.6
$ "/Users/jason.kuhrt/projects/ssense/ms-fastly-purge/node_modules/.bin/flow"
source/test-flow.js:2
  2: const a: Server1 = 1
              ^^^^^^^ identifier `Server1`. Could not resolve name
```

Comment: Could you append your .flowconfig and package.json files? With a standard configuration this should fail. Also try and run flow from command line and append the output

Comment: Done, including source and flow check output.

Comment: That's actually really strange...Maybe there is some global `Server` type that flow is able to find? What happens if you write `Server1` instead of `Server`. If this fails, which it should, what happens if you change your `Server` class name to `Server1`?

Comment: Great point. I had tested that but didn't show it. Now you can see that example too. As for the second request do you mean going into Flow's core library definitions and change the class name? How would I do that as flow-bin is just a binary.

Comment: Ah alright, misread that you are importing the Server from the http module, in that case you can't rewrite the class name...

Comment: I just tried the same, with the same result as you get. Strange. I think there might me a global type import or something like that...But it should definitely produce an error...

Answer (score 0):

Server is not a type. It's a class, so you can't import it as a type. If yout remove the type, everything should work as expected.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize that in Flow classes act as types and values. The only thing I don't understand now is why does it work even without importing the class? E.g. a module containing only `let a : Server` works. Should I update this question to add this aspect or make a new question?